# Back up and restore creating .bak not .cmp

Tags: sharepoint-server, central-administration, backup, restore

When creating a back up of a site using Central administration in Sharepoint, it used to create a couple of files, one being a .cmp.

Now it creates a folder filled with .bak files.

Am I doing something wrong, will this still work. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: sharepoint 2010 or 2013?

Comment: Subsites and below = cmp. Sitecollections and above = bak.

Comment: Sorry Sharepoint 2013!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using site collection backup it will create **".BAK"** by default and if you exporting a list or site it will create **.cmp** file.

.BAK: The BAK file type is primarily associated with 'Backup'.

.CMP is the Content Migration Package for Microsoft Sharepoint.When a Sharepoint website is backed up, a .CMP file is created. File usually contains; Library content, Security settings, User information, Navigation, ustomization and Personalizations.
This file is then generally used to Restore a Sharepoint website.

For more details check:

http://www.nullskull.com/q/10395843/what-is-the-diff-between-bat--bak--cmp-extensions-in-sharepoint-2.aspx

http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/301187-What-are-the-diff-between-bat-bak-cmp-extensions-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your help! Basically I'm trying to create a back up so I can move a site collection to another server.

Any chance you know what the best steps would be, I'll buy you a beer!

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've got it working now. I ended up using Sharepoint management shell, reluctantly and got it working. 

You made me realise I was probably doing it wrong, so thanks!